# Java Array moving elements

Tags: java, arrays

How Do I make it So My highest number simply moves to the first position. This is what I have So far

```
            public static void main(String[] args) {
            //array of 10 numbers
            int numbers[] = new int[]{32,43,53,54,32,65,63,98,43,23};

            //assign first element of an array to largest and smallest
            int smallest = numbers[0];
            int largetst = numbers[0];

            for(int i=1; i< numbers.length; i++)
            {
                    if(numbers[i] > largetst)
                            largetst = numbers[i];}

             System.out.println("Numbers : " + numbers);
             }
             }
```

Comment: Do you only want to have the highest number at the beginning or sort the entire array? (Good sorting algorithms are e.g. [quicksort](http://www.mycstutorials.com/articles/sorting/quicksort), [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aXXWXz5rF64) - another one which might be easier to understand is bubble.. )

Comment: @skofgar at the beginning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //array of 10 numbers
    int numbers[] = new int[] { 32, 43, 53, 54, 32, 65, 63, 98, 43, 23 };

    //assign first element of an array to largest and smallest
    int tmp = 0;
    int largetst = numbers[0];


    for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] > largetst){
            largetst = numbers[i];
        }
    }

    for(int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++){
        if(largetst == numbers[i]){
            tmp = numbers[0];
            numbers[0] =  largetst;
            numbers[i] = tmp;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Numbers : " + numbers[0]);
}
```

Though its not optimal it works please use this approach and further optimize it thanks

Comment: I would avoiding looping twice through the array. It's still quick, but you risk  to have a worst-case run-time complexity of `2n` instead of just `n` to find the largest variable. (It's not bad, but we can avoid this) - alternatively you could save in your first loop, the position of the largest number and then swap without another loop

Comment: Ya this is the result of quick answer as I mentioned in post It should be lot optimized, posted to give OP some idea.

Answer (score 0):

See [Demo](http://goo.gl/bWyTvO)

If I understand your question correctly then this might be the answer :

**

> You only wanted the highest number in the front position of the array.
>   Got no more information

**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        //array of 10 numbers
        int numbers[] = new int[]{32, 43, 53, 54, 32, 65, 663, 98, 43, 23};

        //assign first element of an array to largest and smallest
        int smallest = numbers[0];
        int largest = numbers[0];
        //to keep track of the largest number's index
        int indexOfLargestNumber = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            if (numbers[i] > largest) {
                indexOfLargestNumber = i;
                largest = numbers[i];
            }
        }

        // swap the position of the front number and the highest number
        int temp = numbers[0];
        numbers[0] = largest;
        numbers[indexOfLargestNumber] = temp;

        //printing the whole array
        for(int i = 0;i<numbers.length;i++){
            System.out.print(numbers[i]+"  ");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do **to get the biggest number to the beginning** is: Every time you find a bigger number, swap them with the first one.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        //array of 10 numbers
        int numbers[] = new int[]{32,43,53,54,32,65,63,98,43,23};

        // temporary variable for swapping numbers
        int tmp;

        for(int i=1; i < numbers.length; i++)
        {
                // check if i-th number bigger than first one
                if(numbers[i] > numbers[0]) { 
                        // if yes - swap!
                        tmp = numbers[0];
                        numbers[0] = numbers[i];
                        numbers[i] = tmp;
                }
         }

         System.out.println("Largest number : " + numbers[0]);
 }
```

Alternatively - instead of swapping them - you could just store the position of the largest number and then just swap them after the loop. (Saves some memory and performance)